# Flutter setState from another class

Tags: class, flutter, dart, setstate

So I have this 2 classes

```
class MapsModel {
   MapsModel._();

   ...

   static void Function(VoidCallback) setState;

   static GoogleMap googleMap = new  GoogleMap(
      markers: markers,
      onMapCreated: (GoogleMapController controller) {
        setState((){
        log("Marker added");
        markers.add(
           Marker(
              markerId: MarkerId("<MARKER_ID>"),
              position: LatLng(45.726697, 25.521418)
             )
           );
        });
       },
    );
}
```

and

```
class MapPage extends StatefulWidget {
   MapPage({Key key}) : super(key: key);

   @override
   State<StatefulWidget> createState() => MapPageState();
}

class MapPageState extends State<MapPage> {

@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {

MapsModel.setState = (VoidCallback callback){
  setState(() {
    callback();
   });
  };

 return Scaffold(
     body: MapsModel.googleMap
  );
 }
}
```

So what I want to do is to update the map markers from the first class, using a custom setState function.

The problem is that even the message: Marker Added is shown, the map does not add the marker. Also when I change to another page and back, the marker is added.

Comment: you can add a callback function. But you don't need to use the static keyword there.

Comment: 'Only static members can be accessed in initializers'

Comment: You should pass the function as an argument to the other class in order to make it work like a callback.

Comment: onPressed call back in the Button widget is an example.

Comment: It's kind of all the way around. Also, I want to use MapsModel as a static class,  otherwise, it will have no purpose.

Comment: Why you need to make it static?

Comment: So that when I change the pages, user location and markers won't be added every time.

Comment: You can use a stateful widget and inside the initState method, you setup your one-time logic. Still you don't need the static class.

Comment: I'll see other answers, and otherwise, I will do so

Comment: *"So that when I change the pages, user location and markers won't be added every time."* its perfectly OK with every flutter application - unless you do that 60 times per second ;-) check `Slider` for example: every time you move your finger you have to rebuild the `Slider` again and again

Comment: You can not reuse the `GoogleMaps` widget, you need to rebuild it every time, the widget is tied to its `BuildContext`.